# Counting requests and status codes per URI in a webserver log

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, webserver

Given a typical webserver log file that contains a mixture of absolute URLs, relative URLs, human requests and bots (some sample lines):

```
112.77.167.177 - - [01/Apr/2016:22:40:09 +1100] "GET /bad-credit-loans/abc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7532 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
189.181.124.177 - - [31/Mar/2016:23:10:47 +1100] "GET /build/assets/css/styles-1a879e1b.css HTTP/1.1" 200 31654 "https://www.abc.com.au/customer-reviews/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13D15 Safari/601.1"
110.76.15.146 - - [01/Apr/2016:00:25:09 +1100] "GET http://www.abc.com.au/car-loans/low-doc-car-loans/ HTTP/1.1" 301 528 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
```

I'm looking to list all the URI's requested with status code (200, 302 etc.) and total count of requests i.e.

- http://www.abc.com.au     301    3,900
- /bad-credit-loans/abc/    200    123
- /bad-credit-loans/abc/    302    7

Were it not for the presence of the varying IP addresses, timestamps, referring URLs, and user agents, I would be able to combine `uniq` and `sort` in the standard fashion. Or if I knew all the URLs in advance, I could simply loop over each URL-status code combo with `grep` in its simplest form.

How do we disregard the varying items (user agents, timestamps etc.) and extract just the URLs and their frequency of status code?

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just recognize taht the interesting parts are always on constant filed positions (with respect to space separated fields).

URL is at position 7 and status code is at position 9.

The rest is trivial. You may e.g. use:

```
awk '{sum[$7 " " $9]++;tot++;} END { for (i in sum) { printf "%s %d\n", i, sum[i];} printf "TOTAL %d\n", tot;}' LOGFILES
```

And then sort using sort the result if you need the outpout sorted.

Comment: Beautiful. I knew there existed a UNIX utility to do this sort of thing, I just couldn't recall its name or usage. Thanks.